# can't attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener to my preferences

Tags: java, android, listener, preferenceactivity

First of all - I have tried almoust EVERY post I could find here on stackoverflow, but none solved it for me.

I am using a begginners guide to create a simple app - hence all of the comments.

my problem is that whenever I try attaching a preference to "this" the listener (i have implemented my class as a listener: settings activity implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener) my app will crash!

I'm trying to make the key of each preference it's summary.

Please help me - I've tried every relavent result and did not help. thanks alot!

**This is my Settings Activity class**

> public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
>           implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
>     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
>     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
>
>     Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
>     ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
>     ft.commit();
>
>
>
>     // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
>     // updated when the preference changes.
>     **Here I need to somehow attach the preferences to the listener - but I can't seem to do it without the app crashing**
> }
>
> /**
>  * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
>  * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
>  * is changed.)
>  */
> private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
>     // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
>     //preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
>
>     // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
>     // current value.
>     onPreferenceChange(preference,
>             PreferenceManager
>                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
>                     .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
>     String stringValue = value.toString();
>
>     if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
>         // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
>         // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
>         ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
>         int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
>         if (prefIndex >= 0) {
>             preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
>         }
>     } else {
>         // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
>         preference.setSummary(stringValue);
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the current preference value to it's summary, just add in your preference.xml

```
android:summary="%s"
```

now you dont nead the listener

Comment: thanks for the answer. %s works only for non ListPreference and also it won't update on real time (just if I exit the settings menu and then re-enter it again).

Comment: i take this for ListPreferences and it updates on real time. But i am using a Settings Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in onResume() and onPause() as described in this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Just search for onResume in it.

Comment: Do what? i'm pretty new at android developing and i don't know the proper code lines. thanks.

Comment: How often did you find onResume() in that document? Copy the whole function to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my App and its works without Problem

Have a try, maybe it works

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener


@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        //....... Code
    }
```

[Android Settings Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)